# Superscript Legend Text in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, latex, exponent, superscript

I am currently trying to superscript legend text in R similar to Latex. I have variables such as `"xx", "xxx", "yy", and "zz"` and am wondering if it is possible to automatically convert these to superscripts such as `$x^2$` in Latex. I know of `expression(paste0("x"^"2"))` for ggplot but it is unclear how to implement it or change the text automatically.

```
matrix <- matrix(rexp(200, rate=.1), ncol=20)
df <- data.frame(matrix)
variables <- c("x","y","z","xx","xy","yy","xz","yz","zz","xxx")

df$variables <- variables

new.df <- melt(df, id.vars="variables")

ggplot(new.df, aes(x = variable, y = value, col=variables, group = variables))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()
```

Answer (score 4):

[image] 
you still have to  use expression()

EDIT: you can use rlang ’s parse_exprs() with eval to autmatically convert you vars into expression:

```
#variables_ex <- rep(expression(paste(x^x[y])),10)
##EDIT: universal solution:

library(rlang)

variables <- c("x","y","z","xx","xy","yy","xz","yz","zz","xxx")

exlabel<-paste(variables,"^x[y]",sep="")


ggplot(new.df, aes(x = variable, y = value, col=variables, group = variables))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+ labs(x = variables_ex)+
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Superlegend", labels= eval(parse_exprs(exlabel)))+
  theme( legend.text = element_text(color = "red"))
```

Comment: Is it possible to apply a loop or different function to automatically use `expression(paste())` for the variables in the melted datafame or in the original dataframe?

Comment: sure, why not, probaly  lapply( vector, paste ) and another one with lapply( vector, expression

Comment: That method seems to provide the output `expression(X[[i]], ...)`  for each variable. I've tried `as.expression` but that doesn't seem to provide exactly what I want. Ultimately, as.expression gives `expression("xx")` which wouldn't be what I want and the quotes would need to removed.

Comment: I was trying a for loop but expression didnt behave as expected

Comment: ok i didi it and updated the answer , i hope its clear, otherwise feel free to come back